# How to convert "−" into "-" (minus) in google sheet array?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gAuIXLm5_vApS5kc8QGYyXTlTwugP_Cvx44EmZx0U1c/edit#gid=0) containing data in cell k2:N28. In the column K I have "−" sign and i am unable to calculate the required result in column N. so how to convert "−" into "-" (minus) sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUBSTITUTE to change the symbols, and VALUE to convert it to a number:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(K14,"−","-"))
```

[image]

PS: include this expression inside your formula to multiply for millions, billions, etc.

---

If the data is static you can use FIND AND REPLACE (Ctrl.+H) and replace both symbols:

[image]